# Create a new category based on column values: Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have the following dataframe

df

```
ID  Col_1   Col_2  Col_3 
1     0       1     1  
2     1       0     0
3     1       1     1
4     1       1     0
```

I would like to check each column other than ID have 0 values. If they have write the column name under a new column `Category`. If there are more 0 values with the same row, dublicate the row with different category value. If there is no any 0 value in entire row then leave empty the value of `Category` column.

I would like to get the dataframe as follows.

```
ID  Col_1   Col_2  Col_3   Category
1     0       1     1         Col_1
2     1       0     0         Col_2
2     1       0     0         Col_3
3     1       1     1
4     1       1     0         Col_3
```

Can any one help on this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If need all columns filled by `0` values use matrix multiplication `dot`, then use [`DataFrame.explode`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.explode.html) with splitted values (performance in large df should be worse):

```
df['Category'] = (df.iloc[:, 1:].eq(0).dot(df.columns[1:] + ',')
                     .str.strip(',').str.split(','))
                 
df = df.explode('Category')
print (df)
   ID  Col_1  Col_2  Col_3 Category
0   1      0      1      1    Col_1
1   2      1      0      0    Col_2
1   2      1      0      0    Col_3
2   3      1      1      1         
3   4      1      1      0    Col_3
```

EDIT:

```
s = df.set_index('ID').stack()
df = (df.join(s[s.eq(0)].reset_index(level=1)['level_1'].rename('Category'), on='ID')
        .fillna({'Category':''}))
print (df)
   ID  Col_1  Col_2  Col_3 Category
0   1      0      1      1    Col_1
1   2      1      0      0    Col_2
1   2      1      0      0    Col_3
2   3      1      1      1         
3   4      1      1      0    Col_3
```

Or:

```
s = df.melt('ID').query('value == 0').set_index('ID')['variable']
df = df.join(s.rename('Category'), on='ID').fillna({'Category':''})
print (df)
   ID  Col_1  Col_2  Col_3 Category
0   1      0      1      1    Col_1
1   2      1      0      0    Col_2
1   2      1      0      0    Col_3
2   3      1      1      1         
3   4      1      1      0    Col_3
```

Comment: You edit is quite similar to my solution now

Comment: @mozway - yes, agree.

Comment: I think you could improve your initial solution to split/explode no?

Answer (score 1):

One option is to [`mask`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.mask.html) the non-zero, [`stack`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.stack.html) to get rid of them, and [`join`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.join.html) to add the new column, while duplicating the rows as expected:

```
s = (df.drop('ID', axis=1).mask(lambda d: d.ne(0)).stack()
       .reset_index(level=1)['level_1'].rename('Category'))

df2 = df.join(s)
```

output:

```
   ID  Col_1  Col_2  Col_3 Category
0   1      0      1      1    Col_1
1   2      1      0      0    Col_2
1   2      1      0      0    Col_3
2   3      1      1      1         
3   4      1      1      0    Col_3
```

Answer (score 0):

how about this:

```
df['category']=df[['col1','col2','col3']]
.apply(lambda row:row[row==0].index.values, axis=1)
```

Output:

```
      col1  col2  col3      category
ID                                
0      1     0     1        [col2]
1      0     0     1  [col1, col2]
2      1     1     0        [col3]
```

As you can see ID the index in this example, but it doesn't have to be since you can select which columns you are working with, and then of course you can run:

```
df.explode('category')
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def function1(dd:pd.DataFrame):
    if(len(dd)>1):
        return dd.assign(Category=dd.Category.iat[0].to_list())
    else:
        return dd.assign(Category=dd.Category.map(lambda x:x.max()))

col1=df1.apply(lambda ss:ss.loc[ss.eq(0)].index,axis=1)
df1.assign(Category=col1).groupby("ID",as_index=False).apply(function1)
```

output:

```
   ID  Col_1  Col_2  Col_3 Category
0   1      0      1      1    Col_1
1   2      1      0      0    Col_2
1   2      1      0      0    Col_3
2   3      1      1      1         
3   4      1      1      0    Col_3
```